# external authentication of database users in Db2

Tags: db2, db2-luw, redhat, openldap

For a future project, I am looking into authenticating Db2 database users via LDAP and PAM. However, it seems that LDAP server is deprecated in RedHat:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/7.4_release_notes/chap-red_hat_enterprise_linux-7.4_release_notes-deprecated_functionality

and it is suggested to migrate to `Redhat Identity Management` or `Red Hat Directory Server`. Before setting that up myself I'm curious if anybody knows if authentication for Db2 via any of these replacements work, and what steps that are required in Db2 to switch from LDAP to `Identity Management` or `Red Hat Directory Server`?

Comment: LDAP is a protocol, right? Red Hat Directory Server supports LDAP, therefore standard configuration guidance for Db2 authentication with an LDAP server should apply.

Comment: Thanx, looks like it is possible to use an LDAP client against RedHat Directory Server so it *should* be ok: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_directory_server/9.0/html/administration_guide/ldap-tools-examples. I'll look into RHDS.